# Add sites to Google Custom Search Engine (CSE)

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I am trying to use the Google Custom Search Engine to retrieve news articles from specific sites. I have created a test search engine and add some sites to it to search into.

My problem is that I have a web application to add or remove these site and I want to change theses sites in the CSE programmatically but I couldn't find any way to do it.

Is there ant API to configure my search engine?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, it's under [Creating Custom Search Engines programatically](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api), but unfortunately it is not free :(

Comment: As far I know [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api) is free. [Custom Search JSON/Atom API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing) is 100 search queries per day for free + $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day, for additional requests. [Custom Search XML API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results) is available for Google Site Search customers only.